# how to call stored procedure in Apache Superset?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, apache-superset

Is it possible to call a **stored procedure** (mysql) via the SQL Lab provided in *Apache Superset* ?

Comment: `CALL stored_procedure(parameters);` is common query.

Comment: but Superset doesn't allow this method, that's why I asked

Comment: Asking about Apache Superset **only** do not add [mysql] tag.